# Searching for longitude and latitude by distance in dart

Tags: arrays, flutter, dart

I have a list of longitudes and latitudes (each refers to a postcode), 
as an example in  the form of `{"1111" : [-37.01, 144.8], ...}` (A)

I have another location B [-48.432, 124.432]

I want to find if there are any longitude and latitude within a certain distance from the location b  (5000 meters, 10000 meters, ...) that has an associated postcode.

Any thoughts?

Geodesy package  can help a  little in finding  long and lat,  but could  not figure out the way  for searching A

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `geo-query`. You can use firebase firestore or realtime database to accommodate this need without the requirement of many efforts. [Geoflutterfire](https://pub.dev/packages/geoflutterfire) and [flutter_geofire](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_geofire) are the two libraries which come with the support of what you're looking for.